# Trellis-converging offset and the min-sum algorithm

Tags: forward-error-correction, viterbi-algorithm

I am going through a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1621165) on the design of interleavers for Turbo codes and I am a little bit confused about how to calculate what they call Trellis-Converging offset. They define such parameter of a convolutional code as

> Trellis-converging offset is defined as a doscrete random variable ($W$) on positive integers. The outcome value $w$ corresponds to the event that the trellis converges in $w$ number of symbols in a convolutional code decoder using the min-sum algortihm.

The definition is pretty clear by itself, but I am confused with what they mean by convergence. As far as I know, the min-sum algorithm operates using a fixed set of hidden states on the factor graph passing messages between them, and so if no fixed number is set, the algorithm would need to get the full stream of bits to decode the sequence. However, they say that such algorithm converges for a number of symbols that is a random variable. I have been exhaustively searching in the internet and I have not found information about this TCO, so I was wondering if someone could clarify me this converging criteria or give some reference about the topic.

Comment: I'm only superficially familiar with this specific topic, but my guess at what they mean by trellis convergence is the concept of path merging. At any time, if you trace back the survivor paths through the trellis, there should be some point at which the paths merge, so that their ancestor paths are coincident with one another. At that point, you can make decisions on what the corresponding symbols were. I would guess that the trellis-converging offset is the random variable that describes at what depth this merging occurs.

Comment: Well sounds a pretty plausible explanation. Thank you. Anyway, does such merging of survivor paths always happen, or could it just go to infinity?

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee that they merge, only that they will merge at some point with high probability (where the probability is dependent upon your SNR). This is why the Viterbi algorithm works: if all of your survivor paths agree on what the path through the trellis is, you have all the information that you'll ever have on what the transmitted symbols during that period were. Typical implementations will keep a traceback memory that is sufficiently long that we assume that path merging has occurred (a common size is ~5 times the constraint length of the convolutional code).

Comment: yeah, I see what you mean, but in the paper I cited, they treat such merging length as a random variable, and then us it to estimate the probability that a cycle will happen on the factor graph of the turbo code, so yeah, they should merge with high probability.